Can you continue to work if J1 waiver is approved and H1B is pending?
I work as a postdoc on a J1 visa. I have been granted a J1 waiver based on NOS. My J1 visa expires in three months. I will be applying for H1B visa next week (normal processing time). My question is can I continue to work for the university if H1B is pending? Thanks


My question is can I continue to work for the university if H1B is pending?

No.
You can only continue working while a H1b application is pending while you're applying for extension, and still working for the same employee. You cannot work while your first application is pending.
If you don't get the approval before the J1 status (not visa!) expires, you'll have a gap in your employment authorization and would need to take a leave of absence.

Thanks. I am not sure what do mean by applying for extension. I am working for the same employer. There is funding for one more year after J1 status expiry date. I just received J1 waiver. I am applying for H1B visa next week since I cant extend J1. Since it's normal processing for H1B, my J1 status will likely expire before my H1B gets approved. Will I be able to continue working for the same employer in case I don't get H1B approved (is pending) and J1 status expires?

Extension means... Extending. That's not what you're doing. You're applying for a new status, not extending existing

Okay, that means I need to have a valid H1b status by the time J1 visa expires, is that  right?

That, or take a vacation while you wait

I don't want to leave the country. J1 grace period is only 30 days.

What you want may not necessarily be relevant. But check with the university attorneys, may be you can change status to B2 while you wait.

Applying for B2 visa is a good suggestion. Will be there be an interview? My wife is 31 week pregnant with the due date in late July. Travelling to the consulate will be difficult given that I live in Virginia Beach.

Not visa, status. You don't need to go to any consulate. If you're already in the US then it's an application with USCIS, not the DOS.

Thanks. Glad to know that.
